# Not able to use getRef() of Firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update the data in Firebase database. I have displayed the data in Recyclerview. I need to get the child reference of the position i click in Recyclerview. An not able to use `getRef()` there to get the reference.

[image]

Comment: please post your code add in side of question. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a unique key with

```
String unique = reference.push().getKey();
```

when saving data to firebase, then you can use that unique key to modify content of that node later.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Transactions").child(uniqueId)...
```

You can show your getRef(position) method in your question, maybe another solution can come from there.

Comment: I need for update when there is multiple Childs in database

Comment: Do you want to update multiple children at the same time or do you want to update a specific node when you have multiple child nodes?

Comment: Whichever case, the same thing applies, use each child's unique id to get the child and update it. If my answer, answers your original question, then mark it as correct and ask another question if having issues elsewhere.

Comment: I need to update a specific child when we have multiple Childs. To do so I require getRef(). Am not able to use the function. Is there any alternate function? Or show the database version be changed?

Comment: There is no getRef method in firebase database, at least as far as I know, and database versioning isn't a thing at least in the same sense as SQL databases. But firebase database has event listeners to listen for changes in your database. I suggest you educate yourself on how to use firebase database in general.